# Is there a way to 'design' a custom UIView in storyboard, and use in multiple ViewControllers without adding to any specific controller?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm in need of a custom `UIView` which is to be used in multiple different `ViewControllers`.
Usually when I create a custom `UIView`, I drag an instance of `UIView` into my `ViewController` in storyboard, create a subclass of `UIView`, and point to this subclass in the `Identity Inspector` for the view. From there, I would connect the UI-objects as outlets to the header-file of the subclass.

The view I want to make now, is not supposed to be a part of any specific controller, but should be added to any controller that asks for it. A rogue `UIView`. I know I can create the entire `UIView` programmatically, and just create an instance of it, but I'd like to have it (and design it) in my storyboard.

In Storyboard, the only objects I'm allowed to drag 'outside a ViewController', are other ViewControllers.

I have never used anything other than Storyboard for iOS-developing, but I have come over tutorials which have been using the other mode, *from the olden days*, which looks like what I need. Is it possible to get something similar **into** my storyboard? Or would this require its own setup/design? If so, how?

I was also thinking of solving this with adding a 'phantom' `UIViewController` containing my custom View; designing it there, but instantiate it from the other controllers, but this sounds so hacky..

I'd like to do this with a `UITableViewCell` as well, but I guess that would have the same solution.

Comment: did you get any luck on this?

Comment: @BhaveshLathigara I'm afraid not. I ended up designing the views as individual .xib or .nib or whatever they're called. Exactly what I needed, but I did not get instances of what I designed into the Storyboard. Create a new file, but instead of choosing the regular `Cocoa Touch -> Objective-C class` choose `User Interface -> Empty`. This will open the .xib/nib-editor-thingy, and you can drag whatever you'd like into the screen, eg. a UIView or a tableViewCell. To add them in Storyboard, add a regular view or cell to the controller, and change the class in the inspector to the one you just made

Comment: yes that's right I already used what are you trying to say but thing is that, I don't want to use any xib when I am using Storyboard. ok so lets keep as it is. Now I am using custom view by xib and use it any where. thanks for reply

Answer (score 6):

For your UIView, you should be creating a custom UIViewController in your storyboard and instantiate the view controller to access the view:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
// Access the view using "myViewController.view"
```

This is a very common practice in iOS since storyboards were presented. If you are using multiple storyboards, you should create a new instance of UIStoryBoard with:

```
UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StoryboardName" bundle:nil];
```

And then instantiate the view controller with this instance of the storyboard.

If you want to solely use a UIView, you should be creating a .xib file, i.e. the *olden days* format. To create a custom UITableViewCell, I would absolutely use a .xib file. Your last option would be to create a UIView programmatically, which could be called from any place in your application. Depending on the complexity of this view, this may be a valid option.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can create a custom UIView in storyboard. So in this case, you can create a xib file for that custom view. Then when you want use that view, just use

```
UIView *customView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

to get that view.